# How to get vanilla find-file in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, helm, tramp, ido

Even when i M-x find-file I get the Helm stuff.
I usally also want that, it's just with some Tramp stuff I think there are Problems.

How to get the plain old find-files from vanilla emacs in spacemacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually call `find-file` like this:

```
M-: (call-interactively 'find-file)
```

But you would want to bind to a key by defining a function:

```
(defun native-find-file ()
  "Native Emacs find-file."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'find-file))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC f `") 'native-find-file)
```

Spacemacs way to define key:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "f`" 'native-find-file)
```